add to favorites div function not behaving as expected
I'm creating a dashboard page for a reporting server we have here on site. It's just a collection of links to reports and a brief description of them. I thought it would be nice to allow users to keep a collection of their favorite reports in a div at the top of the page be checking a box next to the report. I've got a js file that is to handle the storing of favorites in localstorage and updating the favorites div on page loads or when a user clicks a checkbox to add it or an X button I fudged to remove it. The first block of code is a snapshot of a portion of the body of the page. The second is the js file. The problem I'm seeing is if there is already a checkbox checked and I check a second box. It seems to be adding the wrong p element although when I deselect some check boxes it sorts itself out. Any help with this weirdness would be appreciated!
<h2>Report Server Dashboard<a href="https://www.freecounterstat.com" title="free website counter"><img src="https://counter6.optistats.ovh/private/freecounterstat.php?c=c4af1t599kzkrhdd7yl7z7qx81nnwrcq" border="0" title="website counter" alt="website counter" style="float:right;"></a></h2>
<div class="ng-binding">
<div class="innerdiv" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 18px; float:left;">
<a style="text-decoration: none" href="/Reports/report/ReportsRun" title="Click here to run a report showing your last 30 days of reports." target="_blank">My last 30 days of reports</a>
</div>
<div class="innerdiv" style="float: inline-start; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px;">
<a style="text-decoration: none" href="mailto:IT@midatlanticcrane.com?subject=Report%20Server%20report%20or%20customization%20request" title="Click here to start an email to the IT department.">***These are all custom reports displaying information pulled from the live Visual database. If you need a report created or modified please reach out to the IT department***</a>
</div>
<div class="innerdiv" id="expander" style="float: inline-start; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px;">
<span id="spanner" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" title="Click to open all sections"></span>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<!--MY FAVORITES-->
<button class="collapsible_nobutton"><strong>MY FAVORITES</strong> - This section contains reports where you've checked the "Add to MY FAVORITES" checkbox.</button>
<div  id="favorites">
    <p><br></p>
</div>

<br>
<!--INFO REPORTS-->
<button class="collapsible"><strong>INFO REPORTS</strong> - General information reports that don't fall under another specific category</button>
<div class="content">
    <p class="paragraph" data-id="1"><input type="checkbox" title="Add to MY FAVORITES section" class="favorite-checkbox" data-id="1"><a href="/Reports/report/INFO%20REPORTS/Customer%20List" target="_blank">CUSTOMER LIST</a>
     - This report provides a listing of customers with address and contact information. It shows customers with a Last Order Date both in the date range you select and customers with no Last Order Date.</p>
    <p class="paragraph" data-id="2"><input type="checkbox" title="Add to MY FAVORITES section" class="favorite-checkbox" data-id="2"><a href="/Reports/report/INFO%20REPORTS/CUSTOMERS" target="_blank">CUSTOMERS</a>
     - This report provides a listing of customers with address and contact information. It has a filterable drop down containing customer names. It also shows the Last Order Date.</p>
</div>

script.js
    // Load favorites from local storage on page load
    var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('newfavorites')) || [];

    // Update the favorites div
    updateFavoritesDiv(favorites);

    // Handle checkbox clicks
    $('.favorite-checkbox').on('change', function() {
        var index = $(this).index('.favorite-checkbox');
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

        if (isChecked) {
            favorites.push(index);
        } else {
            favorites = favorites.filter(function(i) {
                return i !== index;
            });
        }

        // Update local storage and the favorites div
        localStorage.setItem('newfavorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
        updateFavoritesDiv(favorites);
    });



function updateFavoritesDiv(favorites) {
        $('#favorites').empty();
        favorites.forEach(function(index) {
            var $p = $('p').eq(index).clone();
            // Remove the checkbox from the cloned paragraph
            $p.find('.favorite-checkbox').remove();
            var $removeBtn = $('<button class="button" title="Remove from MY FAVORITES section">X</button><span style="width:12px; display: inline-block;"></span>');
            $removeBtn.click(function() {
                // Remove the paragraph from favorites and update the display
                favorites = favorites.filter(function(i) {
                    return i !== index;
                });
                localStorage.setItem('newfavorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
                updateFavoritesDiv(favorites);
            });
            $p.prepend($removeBtn);
            $('#favorites').append($p);
        });
    }
    
});


This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

I'm not super familiar with jQuery, but I feel like $('p') is including the items already added to the favorites, such that if you add "customer list" to favorites, then the next time there is a <p> for the favorites customer list, along with the <p> tags for the info reports section. So the index keeps changing. Perhaps you should use something like $(div.content p) to only look at the <p> tags in your content section.

I'm thinking my using 'p' is the issue as it's not specific enough but so far I've been unable to come up with a working script that might use data-id I added to both the p and the input tags either instead of or in addition to the p.

If you're cloning the ($p), then it's cloning the data-id too. Have you tried  var $p = $('div.content p').eq(index).clone();? It seems to be working for me.

@mykaf that worked brilliantly! The correct p elements are moving to and from the favorites div now. The last thing I'd like to have happen is for the checkbox to be unchecked after it gets added to favorites. I've tried using an event listener on the page itself $('input.favorite-checkbox').change(function(){  $(this).not(':checked')}) and additions to the script.js file but neither seem to be removing the checked state.

for now I've changed the listener to reload the page when someone clicks one of the check boxes. This seems to be working so far.
$(".favorite-checkbox").change(function() {if ($(this).is(":checked")) { location.reload(); }});

@mykaf can you repost your comment about cloning by using the $('div.content p').eq(index).clone(); command as the answer so I can accept it?

Your $('p') selector (var $p = $('p').eq(index).clone();) retrieves all <p> tags, including the items already added to the favorites, such that if you add "Customer List" to favorites, then the next time updateFavoritesDiv() is called, there is a <p> for the favorites customer list, along with the <p> tags for the info reports section, so the index keeps changing.
Since you're only looking to clone the items in the Info Reports section, a more specific selector, $(div.content p) will only retrieve the items in the Info-Reports section and will not attempt to clone the items that have already been added to the favorites.
In short, change var $p = $('p').eq(index).clone(); to var $p = $('div.content p').eq(index).clone(); to eliminate cloning items that have already been added to favorites.
